# Regex starts with and ends with

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
[project_machine 332800MB 256256MB 23%                    
project_machine2 665600MB 512512MB 23%]
```

And I would like to take only the name of the machine, to take something like this:

```
project_machine project_machine2
```

To do it, I tried using regex, and something like this:

^ is for selecting the start of the string
$ is for selecting the end of the string (here, I think, that a whitespace could do the trick)

```
^project+$\s
```

But it does not match.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the string is a single multiline text, you can't use `^`. Try `re.findall(r'\bproject_\S+', text)`

Comment: There is a `[` in the first string which you could optionally match, and omit the `$` as the string does not end after the match that you are looking for `^\[?(project\S+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actually a string, then it contains newlines. You could just split on them to make it easier and avoid regex.

```
s = """[project_machine 332800MB 256256MB 23%                    
project_machine2 665600MB 512512MB 23%]"""

m = []
for machine in s[1:-1].split('\n'):
   m.append(machine.split()[0])

machines_str = ' '.join(m)
```

This is off the top of my head - should work though ...

Explanation:

- `s[1:-1]` is getting rid of the square brackets in 1st and last position.
- `split('\n')` is splitting on the newline to create a list of strings
- Initiate a list and add the first value from each line (machine name) (here the split is splitting on a space, which is the default value for `split`)
- Join this list to get the string you want

I did originally do this with a more complex list comprehension, but I think the loop here is much clearer, and easier to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I really like to use https://regex101.com/ for testing. Because you may not know if your string contains a number, you should indicate that in your expression. Also, your first line does not start with "project_manager", but rather "[". If you only want the name of the machine, you do not need to specify that the string starts with it, simply extract the term:

`project_machine\d*`

`\d`
matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
`*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 1):

`project+` means `projec` followed by one or more `t`. Considering that you want to get match after `[` and not spanning to end of line `^` and `$` are wrong tools for this task. I suggest following way:

```
import re
text = '''[project_machine 332800MB 256256MB 23%                    
project_machine2 665600MB 512512MB 23%]'''
machines = re.findall(r'project\S+', text)
print(machines)
```

output

```
['project_machine', 'project_machine2']
```

Explanation: get `project` followed by any non-whitespaces (`\S`). Note usage of so-called raw-string to make escaping easier. For discussion of usage of raw-strings with `re` module see [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).